# How to get all files from a directory using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app application that has a page where it allows the user to select a .csv file to upload, this file has many columns, one of these columns is a path to a folder with a bunch of pictures.

I want to be able to access this folder and upload all this pictures using js on the client side, apparently all solutions involving the fs library do not work anymore as it's been removed from webpack.

Since the files are hosted in the client side, I need to be able to grab those files programmatically using the js running on the cliente browser, it needs to happen without the user interaction because that CSV file has thousands of lines (there will be thousands of paths to grabs the images from), so the user can't be manually opening the file browser and selecting a directory for each line of that csv file.

To be clear, the only user interaction allowed is the csv file upload, the rest needs to be handled automatically.

How can this be done? And if it can't be done, what would be a work around this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply you can't due to security reasons, user interaction is a must action for file upload.

Comment: Thank you, was fearing this would be the case